# I want to call a volley request from a function that will return the arraylist to some other activity and volley response needs to converted to model

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I want to get the result from volley and then parse the result to create a model arraylist and the functional that calling the volley request should return the arraylist, the function is called from various other activities and code is written by someone else so I need to figure out a way to achieve the same within this class

Here's the full class code

```
class Mock @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) {


    val url = Constant.prefix + "get_short_videos.php"

    fun loadMockData(): ArrayList<StoriesDataModel>? {
      //  val mockData = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.stories_data)
       // val dataString = mockData.bufferedReader().readText()

        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            val data = getData()
        }


        Log.e("Rresponse",dataString+"-");
        val gson = Gson()
        val storiesType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<StoriesDataModel>>() {}.type
        val storiesDataModelList = gson.fromJson<ArrayList<StoriesDataModel>>(dataString, storiesType)




        return storiesDataModelList
    }


    suspend fun getData() = suspendCoroutine<String> { cont ->

        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val postRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST, url,
            Response.Listener { response: String? ->

                Log.e("response",response.toString());
                cont.resume(response.toString())
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error: VolleyError ->
                error.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(context, "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        ) {
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String>? {
                val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                params["mobile"] = context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.prefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("mobile","").toString();
                params["length"] = "0";
                return params
            }
        }
        postRequest.retryPolicy =
            DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
            )
        requestQueue.add(postRequest)


    }
}
```

I tried various different ways given on internet but not able to figure out a way, new to kotlin so don't have much idea about Coroutine, any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance

These suspendCoroutine and CoroutineScope added by me so these might not be something that should be here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to figure out a way to solve the issue, here's answer if anyone needs this

```
class Mock @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) {


    val url = Constant.prefix + "get_short_videos.php"

    private var parentJob = Job()
    private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Main
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

    suspend fun loadMockData(): ArrayList<StoriesDataModel>? {
      //  val mockData = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.stories_data)
       // val dataString = mockData.bufferedReader().readText()

        var dataString = "";
//        val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
//            dataString = getData()
//        }
        scope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val success = async { getData() }
            dataString = success.await()

            Log.e("Rresponse2",dataString+"-");
        }.await();

        Log.e("Rresponse",dataString+"-");
        val gson = Gson()
        val storiesType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<StoriesDataModel>>() {}.type
        val storiesDataModelList = gson.fromJson<ArrayList<StoriesDataModel>>(dataString, storiesType)


        return storiesDataModelList
    }


    suspend fun getData() = suspendCoroutine<String> { cont ->

        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val postRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST, url,
            Response.Listener { response: String? ->

                Log.e("response",response.toString());
                cont.resume(response.toString())
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error: VolleyError ->
                error.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(context, "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        ) {
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String>? {
                val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                params["mobile"] = context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.prefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("mobile","").toString();
                params["length"] = "0";
                return params
            }
        }
        postRequest.retryPolicy =
            DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
            )
        requestQueue.add(postRequest)


    }
}
```

Also requires to make function suspended from the main function called